# how to serve static files in django development server

Tags: django-staticfiles

this question has been answered several times and i have seen almost all related posts,but 
couldn't get css files load. i have this structure in my project:
    mysite
       /templates
           /settings.py
           /urls.py
           /myapp
              /static
                  /css
                     /test.css
in settings.py i have this code:

```
import os
PROJECT_PATH=os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'static',)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

in urls.py i have this code:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import*
from mysite.myapp.views import test
urlpatterns = patterns('',(r'^home/$',test),)

from django.conf import settings
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.staticfiles.views',
                        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$','serve'),
                        )
```

i use this in the template

```
{{STATIC_URL}}css/test.css
```

what wrong am i doing?
is there anything should i be doing?like should add anything in
STATICFILES_DIRS? or in INSTALLED_APPS in settings?
kindly assume that i am an absolute beginner.
i really need an answer.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you still need to pass `STATIC_URL` to the template in your view. The easiest way to do this is using `RequestContext` as long as the 'TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS' include the `static` entry.