# Trying to serve django static files on development server - not found

Tags: python, django

I've followed the instructions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9197599/344286), [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/), and I've even looked at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10644649/344286), but so far I'm unable to get at my static files using `python manage.py runserver`.

These are my (relevant?) settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT '/home/wayne/programming/somesite/static'
STATICFILES_DIRS ('/home/wayne/programming/somesite/static/styles',
                  '/home/wayne/programming/somesite/static/admin')
```

In my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
# The rest of my urls here...
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

I have the following code in my base.html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "styles/main.css" %}">
    {% block styles %}
    {% for sheet in styles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static sheet %}">
    {% endfor %}
```

And I promise I'm not hallucinating:

```
(.env)wayne:~/programming/somesite/static$ pwd 
/home/wayne/programming/somesite/static 
(.env)wayne:~/programming/somesite/static$ ls 
admin  styles
```

However, when navigate to `http://localhost:8000/` my site is missing its stylesheets, and when I go to `http://localhost:8000/static/styles/main.css` I get `'styles/main.css' could not be found`, and trying to navigate to `localhost:8000/static/`, or `localhost:8000/static/styles` it tells me that Directory indexes are not allowed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9613606/344286 actually answers my question - but that wasn't terribly clear from any of the other questions/documentation, so I think (unless this question really is a duplicate) it might be helpful to other folks. If no one puts up a good answer, I'll be writing one myself soon.

Comment: Your situation *is* an exact duplicate of Mohammed's in the linked question, but you've provided a lot more information and it looks like you've tried more things.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Django's handling of static files continue to be slightly confusing, particularly in terms of the naming of relevant settings.

The short answer is to move your static files; instead of

```
/home/wayne/programming/somesite/static
```

put them in

```
/home/wayne/programming/somesite/yourapp/static
```

(where "yourapp" is obviously the name of your main application).

The longer answer is that I think you've (understandably) become confused about the various settings. `STATIC_ROOT` *only* refers to the location **where your static files should end up** after running `manage.py collectstatic`. You don't need this set (as you shouldn't really need `collectstatic`) when developing locally. Either way, `STATIC_ROOT` should always refer to an empty directory.

Your `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting would almost work, except that you've told Django there are two paths where it should find static files

```
/home/wayne/programming/somesite/static/styles
/home/wayne/programming/somesite/static/admin
```

so when you do `{% static "styles/main.css" %}` it will look for

```
/home/wayne/programming/somesite/static/styles/styles/main.css
/home/wayne/programming/somesite/static/admin/styles/main.css
```

and will obviously not find them. What *might* work is

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/home/wayne/programming/somesite/static',)
```

but there's no need to do that, as you can just rely on `django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder` (in [the default STATICFILES_FINDERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS)) and move your static files to an app directory.

Hope this clears things up a little.

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/home/wayne/programming/somesite/static',)` *does* work provided you have a different `STATIC_ROOT`. Personally I prefer this approach to moving static files around.