# Django admin panel interface missing

Tags: python, django

i am using default django admin panel,I have just moved my django site on my live  server, and found the admin panel has no styling with it,but in my local server,everything is fine.In mention i am using **nginx**.To fix this problem, i have just check the path **/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/** and found that there is no /django/contrib/ directory in my virtual environment.There is no /django/contrib/ file in my virtual environment.is that the reason of missing django admin panel interface?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to serve django static files on development server - not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026010/trying-to-serve-django-static-files-on-development-server-not-found)

Comment: You need to collectstatic in your live environment, have you setup your static folders and placed the appropriate declarations in your nginx?
If yes then just run:
`./manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: can you please leave this comment as an answer,if it works fine,i will accept it @petkostas

Answer (score 1):

You need to collectstatic in your live environment, have you setup your static folders and placed the appropriate declarations in your nginx?
If yes then just run:

`./manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: still admin interface is missing,The interface of my main site is fine,but only the admin panel not getting the style.I have do all the things according to your answer,but the problem hasn't solve.

Comment: Did you install the packages after moving from dev to live? are you using a virtual env (you should)?
In your dev machine:
`pip freeze > requirements.txt` then copy that file to the live server, and within your virtualenv:
`pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: actually i found the solution,in my directory,an extra folder namely 'admin' has copied accidentally,this admin folder carries the css of the admin panel,which actually overriding my main admin panels css.